# Where can I download OpenStreetMap data by geographic region?

Tags: openstreetmap, download

I want to use OpenStreetMap data for an ArcEngine application I'm working on, and I need the data to be stored locally. I don't want to download the entire planet.osm file, but rather by state, county, region, etc. **Are there any resources where I can download OSM data by geographical region?**

Comment: related: Downloading OpenStreetMap Data http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6933/downloading-openstreetmap-data?rq=1

Comment: would like to add [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/ "Download Server for OSM Data a GeoFabrik") to the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Portions of OSM data consisting of a specific geographic area are called [Extracts.](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm)

Extracts within the USA are only available by [states](http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/north-america/us/) and a [few metropolitan areas.](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) . These are often updated daily (unlike cloudmade, which hasn't updated theirs since December!)

If you want something more specific like a county or a municipal boundary), you can download the appropriate state extract and then use a tool like [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) to filter out all data within a specific area to create your own 'extract'.

[3](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis): http://metro.teczno.com/ and http://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/

Comment: http://download.geofabrik.de/openstreetmap/ +1

Answer (score 6):

You can also check out these sites for osm and open gis data.

1. OpenStreetMap Extracts, [here](http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/)
2. OpenStreetMap derived data, [here](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data)
3. Open GIS data, [here](http://www.csc.fi/english/research/sciences/geo/gis/open_data/)
4. GIS Datasets, [here](http://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/)

in addition to these;

Planet.osm/diffs [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm/diffs) and [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm)

i hope it helps you...