# Is it possible to create a KML to list the road names within a buffer?

Tags: buffer, google-earth, road

I often need to know the road names within a given buffer of a polygon. Is it possible to create a KML that would stick a push pin in the roads and list the name so I could see them all in a drop down menu? I am new to GIS data manipulation.

Comment: Are you wanting this to be static or dynamic?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marybeth. I need it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.  But it's not as easy as performing a query in Google Earth/Maps.

You will need a dataset of Street Data. I recommend using Open Street Map data [See this Q&A on downloading OSM data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30231/where-can-i-download-openstreetmap-data-by-geographic-region).

From that download, you will need to work on the KML. Depending on whether you are working on a [static map](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut?hl=en) or a [dynamic map](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GoogleEarth_Dynamic_KML), will determine what direction you take with your KML code.