# OpenStreetMap data into ESRI CityEngine

Tags: openstreetmap, cityengine

I am trying to download building footprints from OpenStreetMap so I can import them into ESRI's CityEngine but I am only able to download road files (as routes), as seen below.

I am trying to download a section of Seoul (Gangnam) to display the area in CityEngine.

I am new to downloading OSM data.

[image: Image 1 example]

[image: Image 2 example]

Comment: Have you looked at this Question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6933/downloading-openstreetmap-data?

Answer (score 4):

Use the 'Export' tab on the OSM website to export an *.osm file.

You can then use the 'Import' option on the File menu in CityEngine 2012.1 to import osm files.
You can then select / deselect features to include in your model.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I just saw your answer on Twitter as well. I didn't know I can import OSM files directly into CityEngine since I'm just starting out with that software as well!

Answer (score -1):

you can use http://www.osm974.re/osm2gis/ to convert OSM data to SHPs

Comment: thanks for answer but please explain your answer in detail