# How to get shapefiles or kml files for city map in India?

Tags: openstreetmap, data, india

I am doing a project.

In that I'm using QGIS for visualization purpose.

Using the OpenLayers plug-in i am getting map of a city.

What i want to know is whether I can convert that into shapefiles or KML files?

Or is there any process of getting shapefiles or kml files of a city's roads?

Comment: closely related to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6933/downloading-openstreetmap-data

Answer (score 3):

The background image of the Openlayers plugin is a set of tiles in raster format. You can not convert that to anything useful.

You can

- digitize the features you want on the basis of the background
- download Openstreetmap data (one of the available backgrounds of Openlayers) and filter that for the data you need.

Answer (score 3):

This [link](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/india.html) from geofabrik.de provide shape files for roads and other features from open layers categorized into countries and for India covering almost all urban area. For urban boundary or district boundary shape files for India this [link](http://datameet.org/wiki/indiangeospatialdata) would be helpful.

Comment: can we get the longitude and latitude for a location in QGIS maps by using this map...

Comment: Yes, it can be,

Comment: Thank You boss those maps very helpful... Is in QGIS i am getting all information for location road(Eg:one way,tunnel ) like that.But long lat are not getting manually if we place cursor I am able to see the lat long.

Answer (score 2):

You can also download from DIVA-GIS:

http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata

Select India and then select the subject of the attributes such as:

- Administrative areas (boundaries)
- Roads
- Railroads
- Land cover
- Population

Comment: but need the area name and some information....

Comment: If you select **Administrative areas**, you will receive several shapefiles of differing levels with area names and other pieces of information.