# How to get all feature and attribute list from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, features, fields-attributes

I want to get the list of all features their attribute list for my application from OpenStreetMap. Where can I get that?

Comment: Please elaborate your question e.g what application you are using,what you tried so far, in what format you want to collect OSM data etc.

Comment: I don't want to collect the whole data I just want to collect the name of the features from openstreetmap in any format.(csv type).I have searched the home wiki page for that

Comment: Please use the **edit** button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications rather than creating a trail of comments that potential answerers may or may not read.

Comment: try http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6933/downloading-openstreetmap-data

Comment: Visit https://help.openstreetmap.org and search for "CSV" ... all information you need is there!

Answer (score 3):

using arcgis editor for OSM, you can auto extract features and symbolize it, also it allows you to extract information to table.

http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/openstreetmap